# How can I target only visible objects with nth-child?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I have 5 items, and a button above them to inform how many items will be displayed.
For each item I have a different background image.

The problem is that when a person hits an item, that item will be removed and another item will be `appended` with jQuery and when a new item is appended, it goes to the end of the line, making it the 5th element and then making it with the background of the 5th item but there are times that the 5th item is the only visible and it should be with the background of the 1st item.

Here is a JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wmerussi/csqge7jr/

In the beginning you have 5 items, note that the 5th item is blue, now if you choose to display only 1 item, and click that item to remove it, the other item will be blue (the color of 5th item).

Is it possible to have only the visible items targeted?
Or is it possible to re-arrange the visible `<li>`s to the beginning of the list?

HTML:

```
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="four">4</div>
<div class="five">5</div>

<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    for(var i=0; i<5 ;i++) {
        if(i < num) {
            $('li').eq(i).fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('li').eq(i).fadeOut();
        }
    }
});

$(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(function() {$(this).remove();});
    $(this).parent().append('<li></li>');
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

li:nth-child(1), .one {
    background-color: green;
}


li:nth-child(2), .two{
    background-color: orange;
}

li:nth-child(3), .three{
    background-color: red;
}

li:nth-child(4), .four{
    background-color: pink;
}

li:nth-child(5), .five{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**update**
How to reproduce the issue
click on my JSFiddle and then chose to show only 1 item (the green "1" box at top). After that if you click that visible item to remove it (with jQuery), you will see that the appended items will be blue, because they are being appended to the end of the ul list, making it the 5th element. But it is the first visible item, so it should be green.

Comment: _“Is it possible to have only the visible items targeted?”_ – not with the `nth-child` selector, because that only cares about what’s in the DOM, not about what might be “visible” or not. But since you are using jQuery already to get the elements to show in the first place, you could easily use the classes you got in your CSS only, and assign the correct class to the elements based on what’s shown or not.

Comment: I guess I would have to turn all backgrounds into classes and re/apply the classes to the visible elements?

Comment: I don't get your question. `but there are times that the 5th item is the only visible`, can you tell how to reproduce this?

Comment: @Ejay, click on my JSFiddle and then chose to show only 1 item. After that if you click that visible item to remove it (with jQuery), you will see that the appended items will be blue, because they are being appended to the end of the `ul` list, making it the 5th element

Comment: Added to your question

Comment: _“I guess I would have to turn all backgrounds into classes”_ – don’t you have that already – `.one`, `.two` etc. …?

Comment: @CBroe The class is for the `<div>` and not for the `<li>`

Comment: And what is stopping you from applying that same class to the `li`? After all, the selector contains the class selector only, so it is applicable to whatever element you give that class to …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution would be to create a function that manages adding removing classes to items based on their position and visibility, and call that function after each event that updates the items in some way.
This way you can keep the items classes management separate from the code that updates the items

```js
$(function() {

  //the class management function
  function updateElemClasses() {
    //all color based classes the lists can have
    var classes = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

    //wait for fadeout to happen. Fadeout could take longer but this is just a proof of concept
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $('li:visible').each(function(idx) {
        $(this).removeClass(classes.join(' ')).addClass(classes[idx]);
      })
    }, 500);

  }

  $('div').on('click', function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      if (i < num) {
        $('li').eq(i).fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('li').eq(i).fadeOut();
      }
    }
    updateElemClasses()
  });

  $(document).on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $(this).parent().append('<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li>');

    updateElemClasses()
  });

  updateElemClasses();
});
```

```css
/* you do not need nth-child now */

div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.one {
  background-color: green;
}
.two {
  background-color: orange;
}
.three {
  background-color: red;
}
.four {
  background-color: pink;
}
.five {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="four">4</div>
<div class="five">5</div>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Although I didn't understand it completely, it worked for me :). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You add or remove a `visible` class to your elements.

And then, use those selectors instead of `:nth-child`:

```css
.visible, .one {
    background-color: green;
}
.visible ~ .visible, .two {
    background-color: orange;
}
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible, .three {
    background-color: red;
}
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible, .four {
    background-color: pink;
}
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible, .five {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  var num = $(this).text();
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (i < num) {
      $('li').eq(i).addClass('visible').fadeIn();
    } else {
      $('li').eq(i).removeClass('visible').fadeOut();
    }
  }
});
$('li').addClass('visible');
$(document).on('click', 'li.visible', function() {
  $(this)
    .removeClass('visible')
    .fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    })
    .parent().append('<li class="visible"></li>');
});
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
.visible,
.one {
  background-color: green;
}
.visible ~ .visible,
.two {
  background-color: orange;
}
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible,
.three {
  background-color: red;
}
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible,
.four {
  background-color: pink;
}
.visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible ~ .visible,
.five {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">3</div>
<div class="four">4</div>
<div class="five">5</div>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tryed to use it on the JSFiddle, but it didn't work.

Comment: @William I forgot to add/remove the class when the `div`s were clicked.